# Regular Expression that accepts any number letters and '-' '\'

Tags: php, regex, html

Can you suggest regular expressions for both PHP and HTML5 that accepts numbers, letters and '-' '\' ?

BUT any string must have a length between 4 and 30 chars.

HTML 5:

```
 <input name="route" id="route" type="text" required title="4 to 30 characters/ 0-9 / A-Z/./'/'"   pattern="????"/>
```

PHP:

```
!(preg_match(?))
```

Comment: Can you show what you have so far? That generally helps to give readers an idea with what part you need help with. HTML5 doesn't have regular expressions, so I assume you want to do this in PHP. Also, it helps to say what you are doing - for example, if you are parsing HTML5 with a regular expression, the general advice is not to, since there are HTML parsers in PHP that will do a better job.

Comment: You'll want a character class here (square brackets) and a length specification (curly ones).

Comment: @halfer HTML5 does technically speaking have regexes, in the `<input>`'s HTML5 pattern attributes

Comment: @Joeytje50, ah right, thanks! In that case, the OP could be asking for either - clarification required, I think.

Comment: @halfer html 5 has a required pattern!

Comment: Indeed @Gabriele, see the earlier comment to that effect. Are you after a PHP or an HTML5 regex? There may not be any difference, but it helps to get into the habit of being specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this Regex

```
^([A-Za-z0-9\/-]{4,30})$
```

Comment: Never put dashes in the middle of your groups

Comment: If you put dashes in the middle of your group, such as `[a-z]`, you will match a range from `a` to `z`. In this case, the dash is right after a range, so it won't do anything special, but it's still really bad habit to put dashes in the middle of a group match.

Comment: @GabrieleMandalari I'm not sure what you're trying to do. [this code Namibi posted seems to work just fine](http://regex101.com/r/sL8sS4)